# How to include a deployment.properties file of environment variables in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: deployment, wso2, environment-variables, wso2-identity-server

I want to include a properties file of environment variables to better integrate between environments in AWS deployment of WSO2 Identity Server. I could put all the environment variables in line in the wso2server.sh, but it would be better to inject a properties file that has all the variables I need.

I am trying to include:

```
-Ddeployment.conf="$CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/etc/dev-env.properties" \
```

in the wso2server.sh where my dev-env.properties has variables that I want to include in the xml configurations. An example being the usr-mgt.xml connection string:

```
<Property name="ConnectionURL">${user.mgt.connection.url}</Property>
```

I could do `-Duser.mgt.connection.url="connection-string" \` but I have about 20 properties that I currently want to set this way and would prefer to keep them all in one file instead of in line environment variables. I found this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@shan1024/overriding-configurations-in-wso2-products-using-deployment-properties-file-f096e96f782d) 
describing something like what I am looking for but I'm not sure it's exactly what I want and it was unclear how to implement this.

Do I need to write a Java Util class to read these environment variables from the properties file or is there a simpler way to do this? And if I need a utils class what would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this feature will support from the WSO2 products which are based on Carbon Kernek 5 and onwards. But at the moment most of the WSO2 products are based on kernel version 4.0. Therefore I think you can't get this done with existing WSO2 products.